# How can I compute the missing volume by looking at the pressure changes?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

Disclaimer: I'm not in any shape used to deal with physics and forgive me in advance if this question is either out of scope of wrongly formulated.

I have a very practical problem. I have a container that contains a liquid which is under pressure (the air above the liquid, inside the container, is under pressure). I also have a sensor inside the container that tells me, with very high frequency and precision, what is the current pressure of the air.

Now, imagine this container has a valve through which the liquid is expelled. Considering that there is no extra air being pumped into the container, I can perfectly observe the pressure dropping over time, by reviewing the data provided by the pressure sensor.

My question is: how can I compute the volume of liquid that was expelled by only looking at the pressure over time? I have naively assumed that I could just compute the upper integral of the pressure/time curve during the period the valve was open. Is this remotely near a correct answer?

**EDIT**: Actually what I am looking for is the flow-rate of the liquid that was expelled, not the volume per se.

**EDIT 2**: To elaborate better on the problem I've compiled the pictures/diagrams bellow.

The first image depicts the environment as I tried to describe above, hope it makes it clear.

[image: Problem diagram]

The second image depicts a sample of readings from the pressure sensor during one opening of the valve. As you can tell it is clear that the pressure drops, my hope is that the rate (slope?) of the drop could indicate the flow rate of the expelled liquid.

[image: Pressure readings sample]

Best,

Comment: The flow rate is complicated. Does the valve expel the liquid into air? If so, then flow rate is proportional to square root of pressure. If it's flowing into a thin tube, then it's proportional to pressure. Most likely it's a combination of these. You can look up orifice flow rates, but the best answer is to experiment.

Comment: Is your pressure measurement continuous, or are you using some type of digital sampled data system to take your pressure measurement?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The valve expels the liquid into a tube. The valve works like a faucet, meaning it influences the flow rate.

Comment: @DavidWhite The measurements are taken every 60ms, which is enough resolution  to say that it is almost a continuous sampling

Comment: Do you know the total initial volume of liquid in the device before you open the valve?

Comment: @DavidWhite I know the initial volume of the system (30 liters) thereafter I would only be able to know the initial volume before opening the valve if I discounted the volume expelled for every time the valve was opened.

Comment: OK.  I may have a solution, but I need to know if you are cycling this device.  If so, there will be small errors in volume as you charge and discharge the liquid container, and those errors will add up over time, meaning that you will lose track of the liquid volume in the container.

Comment: @DavidWhite What do you mean exactly by cycling?

Comment: Do you determine the liquid volume in the container before each discharge of liquid, or do you determine the liquid volume once and go through several cycles of refilling and discharging before determining a new liquid volume in the container?

Comment: @DavidWhite It's option 2. Initially the container is filled with 30 liters which are, as you put it, cycled through several discharges before emptying the container and inserting a new one.

Comment: OK.  I'll publish what I have tomorrow (8/04/19), but be aware that errors will accumulate as you cycle your container.

Comment: @DavidWhite eager to see your response!

Comment: You can expect somewhere between linear and quadratic. From what you say it sounds closer to quadratic. But do the experiment; that's the only good way to tell. Any math you do will only be approximate, at best.

Answer (score 1):

A practical approximation is to assume adiabatic expansion of the gas.

$$P_iV_i=P_fV_f$$
$$\frac{P_i}{P_f}V_i=V_f$$
$$\Delta V=V_f-V_i=\frac{P_i}{P_f}V_i-V_i=V_i\left(\frac{P_i}{P_f}-1\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! Can you please provide me your 2 cents after my edit above? What I'm actually looking for is the flowrate of the expelled liquid, not the volume

Answer (score 0):

Given a known initial volume of liquid (assume water) in the container, it is known that as water flows out of the container, the compressed air on the outside of the water bladder and inside the container, expands.  Using the ideal gas law, it should be possible to calculate the rate of water flow based on the air pressure in the container.

Let

$P_1$ = the air pressure in the container at the start of a timing period

$V_1$ = the initial volume of air in the container, before any liquid is removed

$P_2$ = the air pressure in the container as water is flowing, at the end of a timing period

$V_2$ = the volume of air in the container as water is flowing

$\Delta P$ = change in pressure in the container over a timing period

$\Delta V$ = change in volume in the container over a timing period

$\Delta t = t_2 - t_1$, which is the length of a timing period

Assuming that the compressed air temperature remains constant, the following derivation applies:

$P_1V_1=P_2V_2$

$P_2-P_1=P_1\frac{V_1}{V_2}-P_1$

$P_2-P_1=P_1\frac{V_1-V_2}{V_2}$

$\frac{\Delta P}{P_1}=\frac{-\Delta V}{V_2}$

$\frac{-V_2}{P_1}\Delta P = \Delta V$

Looking at these changes in pressure and volume over short time intervals leads to:

$\frac{-V_2}{P_1}\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$

It is known that $V_2$ must follow the ideal gas law, so that law can be used to eliminate $V_2$:

$V_2 = \frac{nRT}{P_2}$

$\frac{-nRT}{P_2}\frac{1}{P_1}\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta t}=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$

The number of moles of air in the container, "n", can also be eliminated with the ideal gas law:

$n=\frac{P_1V_1}{RT}$

$\frac{-P_1V_1}{RT}\frac{RT}{P_2}\frac{1}{P_1}\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta t}=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$

Cancellation of terms yields:

$\frac{-V_1}{P_2}\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta t}=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$

If $V_1$ is known, the flow rate, which is $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$, can be calculated by measuring the rate of pressure drop in the container.  Note that the value of $P_2$ should probably be an average of container pressure at the start of a pressure measurement and the pressure in the container at the end of a pressure measurement.